# large image not shrinking to css grid container on browser resize

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-grid

I have a simple grid layout with a main area on top and a nav area on bottom. I am just starting using css grid and am having trouble with having a responsive image that stays in the grid container. It is not shrinking responsively when the browser resizes, and is extending past the border of its container. I have tried min-height/min-width: 0, object-fit: contain, changing sizes from vh/vw to 100%, changing max-widths/heights to different px and % sizes, and I still can't figure out how to make this responsive using grid. I searched pretty extensively, but nothing seems to have helped. I'm sure it's something simple that I missed, but I'm at a loss right now.

I also want to use just HTML and CSS if possible without any libraries like Bootstrap.

I put some outlines on different elements to make it easier to see what's happening that don't seem to be showing in the snippet, so if it's easier to inspect the code here is a link to the site:
https://mountainflow.design/portfolio.html

```css
/* Box Sizing */
html {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
   -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
   -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
   box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* body 100% with no margin or padding */
html {
   height: 100vh;
}

body {
   min-height: 100vh;
}

html,
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

/* =================== Start Style Sheet ==========================
================================================================ */

body { 
   background-color: #000000;
   color: #ffffff;
}

a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Main Section */

.folio-main-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: 80% 1fr;
   height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

.folio-main {
   outline: blue solid thin;
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
 grid-row: 1 / 2;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 0;
 min-width: 0;
}

.gallery-container {
 outline: pink solid thin;
 max-width: 970px;
 min-height: 0;
 min-width: 0;
 position: relative;
}

/* .slideshow {
 display: none;
} */

.slideshow img.responsive { 
 max-width: 970px;
 height: auto;
}

/* .caption {

} */

/* Nav Section */

.folio-nav {
   outline: red solid thin;
   grid-column: 1 / 2;
   grid-row: 2 / 3;
   align-self: end;
   justify-self: end;
   padding: 2em;
}

.folio-nav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.folio-nav li {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee, rgb(158, 104, 246));
   background-clip: text;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

li {
   margin-left: 2em;
}

/* Button animations */

.folio-nav li:nth-child(1) {
 position: relative;
 left: -1000px;
 animation: navFadeIn 3s ease-in 2s forwards;
}

.folio-nav li:nth-child(2) {
 position: relative;
 left: -1000px;
 animation: navFadeIn 3s ease-in 1.85s forwards;
}

.folio-nav li:nth-child(3) {
 position: relative;
 left: -1000px;
 animation: navFadeIn 3s ease-in 1.7s forwards;
}

.folio-nav li:nth-child(4) {
 position: relative;
 left: -1000px;
 animation: navFadeIn 3s ease-in 1.55s forwards;
}

.folio-nav li:nth-child(5) {
 position: relative;
 left: -1000px;
 animation: navFadeIn 3s ease-in 1.4s forwards;
}

@keyframes navFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 85% {
  left:0;
 }
 89% {
  left: -5px;;
 }
 93% {
  left: 0;
 }
 97% {
  left: -3px;
 }
 100% {
  left:0;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="folio-main-container">
        <div class="folio-main">
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <div class="slideshow">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://sheltered-meadow-24497.herokuapp.com/" title="Fur Butlr">
                        <img class="responsive" src="https://github.com/mountainflow/portfolio_03/blob/master/assets/images/furButlr_970x600.png?raw=true" alt="Fur Butlr" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">Fur Butlr</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="gallery-container">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://chat-meme-3fbf6.firebaseapp.com/" title="ChatMeme">
                    <img src="./assets/images/chatMeme_970x600.png" alt="ChatMeme" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://mighty-everglades-33601.herokuapp.com/" title="Friend Finder">
                    <img src="./assets/images/friendFinder_970x600.png" alt="Friend Finder" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <a target="_blank" href="./assets/images/liri.gif" title="Liri">
                    <img src="./assets/images/liri_970x600.png" alt="Liri" />
                </a>
            </div> -->
        </div>

        <div class="folio-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="./assets/CV/greg-olson-resume.pdf" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="About Me">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/mountainflow" title="GitHub">Github</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/greg-olson-mountainflow" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Once I get the grid responsiveness worked out this will be a slideshow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: 100%` will work for what you need.

Comment: Adding that to the image helps with resizing, but not with the image overflowing its container and into the nav area of the grid. I'm trying to have the image resize in order to not extend outside of the folio-main area.